# Splitting a dataframe column using first n characters of a string

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I'm still new to R and have been trying to solve this for a couple of hours now. I have a .csv with two columns, I would like to split the first column into two columns after the first 3 characters and then I could maybe delete the leading space on the second column.

---

I'm sure this must be addressed somewhere but I cant find the right terminology to describe my problem.

---

I can't use a " " delimetter as some of the column values have two words in them. 
I have tried creating a new column and then finding a way to split the string but to no avail.

```
    primary_area       value
1  101 Kungsladugård  8164
2  102 Sanna          1580
3  103 Majorna        10032
4  104 Stigberget     15182

to this

   id   primary_area   value
1  101  Kungsladugård  8164
2  102  Sanna          1580
3  103  Majorna        10032
4  104  Stigberget     15182
```

Comment: Could you rather make a reproducible example with dput()?

Comment: I found the solution using seperate, thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the code below

```
df <- with(df, data.frame(id = gsub("(^\\w{3}).*","\\1",primary_area),
                          primary_area = gsub("^\\w{3}(.*)","\\1",primary_area),
                          value = value))
```

such that

```
> dfout
   id  primary_area value
1 101 Kungsladugård  8164
2 102         Sanna  1580
3 103       Majorna 10032
4 104    Stigberget 15182
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do:

```
cbind(read.table(text = df$primary_area,
      strip.white = TRUE, col.names = c("id", "primary_area")), value = df$value)
   id  primary_area value
1 101 Kungsladugård  8164
2 102         Sanna  1580
3 103       Majorna 10032
4 104    Stigberget 15182
```